# Flurry API crashing iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, flurry

My app is crashing using iOS5 and iOS4.3 iPhone simulators in Xcode 4.2, the stack trace shows BAD_ACCESS signal in [FlurryAPI stopBackgroundTask] method.

While in the iOS4.3 simulator the app is only crashing when sending the app to background, in iOS5 is crashing always.I am attaching a picture of the debug navigator showing the thread where the BAD_ACCESS is happening.

On the other hand the app is working fine using a real device.

Any ideas of how can I get more information of what is going on and why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: Getting the exact same thing, after upgrading to the latest Flurry lib (and replacing my old FlurryAPI calls with FlurryAnalytics...)

Comment: It is something that happen in the thread that Flurry is creating for its agent when we execute [FlurryAnalytics startSession:FLURRYAPIKEY] in our code. Still don't know how to check from where the call, which is causing the problem, comes from.

Comment: Same problem here, couldn't find a fix. I updated to Flurry 3.0.4 and still get the issue in Simulator, both 4.3 and 5.0.

Comment: I am commenting out this line in my code [FlurryAnalytics startSession:FLURRYAPIKEY] just to run the app in the simulator... I know it is not ideal but I didn't find something better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've worked around this issue by adding the following to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
        [FlurryAnalytics setSessionReportsOnPauseEnabled:NO];
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

Flurry analytics does not run other than main Thread. It might crash on background thread.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a zombie - you have a situation where you're using code after you've released it.  The retain count reaches zero, so the system dealloctes and re-uses the memory, then you make a change through the original reference.  Now you have two different references to the same memory, each of which expects a different object to be there.  In your case, one of the references is within flurry.

The reason for your device/simulator differences is the different memory allocation schemes the two architectures use - the simulator seems to re-use memory very aggressively.

Enable NSZombie and run in the debugger.  If you're lucky, it will give you the object and the point it's used after deallocation.

Enable NSZombie: Menu 'Product', 'Edit Scheme...'  'Run' page, 'Diagnostics' tab, tick 'Enable Zombie Objects'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but enabling NSZombies doesn't give me any extra info :(